# Ubuntu 18.04: Authentication Error on loging after lock

Tags: 18.04

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and since today whenever I lock my system and try to log back in using my password, it shows the 'in progress' spinner for few seconds then I get the error message "Authentication error". I can successfully log in on the first start though.

I have tried to force disable Wayland by uncommenting the line `#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` but it had no effect. I was originally using Xorg as well.

I've checked for any available system updates in hope of getting a fix but none are available. What can I do to investigate into and fix this error?

Update: I re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 to get rid of the issue.

Comment: No responses! Is there really nothing that can be done? The upvotes indicate that others are facing this issue as well. Well, after spending about 3 hours trying to resolve this, I finally re-installed the operating system and spent the weekend setting up the laptop.

Comment: What made you think Wayland was the problem?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix some posts on the Internet.

Comment: Next time please include a link to the reference you were following so that others can confirm it is relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix got it.

Comment: I also got it. My question is, why this happened? Before that, I just reinstalled the system python. (I don't believe, that it should be connected).

Answer (score 14):

The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell` command did not work for me.

What did work was changing `fs.inotify.max_user_watches`. I used [this solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20210613143947/https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/question/115963/gnome-authentication-error-when-logging-in-after-lock/) (also [here](https://medium.com/@at15/ubuntu-change-fs-inotify-max-user-watches-for-idea-f5f5d6651e7f)).

#### Temporary solution

```sh
sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288  # sysctl - configure kernel parameters at runtime
```

or

```
sudo -i
echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
exit
```

#### Permanent solution

Modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sudo echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

#### Related

- [How to change value of /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353041/how-to-change-value-of-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches)
- [How to set and understand fs.notify.max_user_watches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444998/how-to-set-and-understand-fs-notify-max-user-watches)

Comment: it seems like an update has been provided by Canonical having `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576` setting inside the `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` file. unfortunately up to date the problem hasn't been solved with this update yet

Comment: It works like a charm!

Comment: Glad you found this.  It has been driving me crazy!

Comment: Can you inline the steps here? the page https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/115963/gnome-authentication-error-when-logging-in-after-lock/ is not found. i installed 18.10 fresh today.

Comment: from https://medium.com/@at15/ubuntu-change-fs-inotify-max-user-watches-for-idea-f5f5d6651e7f edit /etc/sysctl.conf to add/ edit the line:  
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22

Comment: @slimbob - could you elaborate why is this an issue in the first place and why does this solution fix it?

Answer (score 14):

You can unlock the screen from terminal and command line, avoiding reboot. This is a temporary solution while you work on a permanent one.

On the login screen, Press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F3</kbd> to open a terminal, or use SSH to access from another computer. To unlock all sessions, type `sudo loginctl unlock-sessions`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + F2</kbd>, for example, to go back to your (now unlocked) session.

For more details, please see [Unlock login screen using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341014/unlock-login-screen-using-command-line)

This does not solve the underlying problem, but lets you quickly get back to your session to save your work and try configuration changes, without having to reboot.

Comment: Damn. I was installing gnome 41 and left the oc unattended and came back to this shit 

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem.  After running the following I can re-login from the lock screen.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell
```

Comment: I ultimately re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 to get rid of the issue.

Comment: I came across my solution because you re-installed.  I was looking for other ways than a full re-install.  I thought I might re-install Gnome only since Gnome handles the login screen now.  And a comment on a post (some other Gnome weirdness from a while ago) about re-installing Gnome was a suggestion to use dpkg to reconfigure.  So I tried that, and my lock screen issue went away.

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: Worked for me!!!. My question is, why this happened? Before that, I just reinstalled the system python. (I don't believe, that it should be connected)

Answer (score 4):

In order to resolve this issue open `/etc/sysctl.conf` file as root user in your favourite text edior. Now add `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288` at the bottom of the file and save it. Run `sudo sysctl -p` command in terminal to persist the changes you made in sysctl. And its done !

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and by heading into a new terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) I ran `sudo service gdm restart` which switched back to a graphical login. Logging in didn't work and the warning on the terminal said a warning about not being able to watch the file system, not enough disk space. The fix was increasing the `max_user_watches` as found in [this article](https://medium.com/@at15/ubuntu-change-fs-inotify-max-user-watches-for-idea-f5f5d6651e7f).

Comment: Yes it is worked for me... thank you for the solution.

Comment: Fantastic. It got rid of a persistent (uncancelable) 'Authentication required to perform file operations' dialog at the top left of the screen for me. However, it does close all applications, so it is not unlike a logout/login without any questions to save work. Careful; you will loose work if you have not saved things.

Answer (score 2):

Got this problem in Ubuntu 20, none of the solutions worked and I cannot even see the login screen after reboot....
Have to jump to the console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login through tty.

I solved this problem by reinstall gnome and ubuntu desktop in tty:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

Comment: The reason for this is that somehow gdm3 got uninstalled or deactivated. In my case the Ubuntu switched over to lightdm, but logging in was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The gnome reconfigure command worked for me even after a completely clean reinstall failed. I had also tried to use the wayland log in and got stuck in a log in loop and had also tried to purge upstart which was apparently causing issues for some users.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I ran the following to ensure all my packages were up to date

1. sudo apt update & apt upgrade

The above displayed a message "6 packages to upgrade"
I then ran the following to do an upgrade.

2. sudo apt full-upgrade

Then reboot my desktop.

3. sudo reboot

After reboot, the login screen should allow you to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, gnome wasn't proper. my error was 
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown group 'geoclue' in statoverride file

So I had to go to statoverride and groupadd geoclue
But still whatever files were there in statoverride file they were showing the same error, I had to groupadd all the groups, then 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session ubuntu-desktop
 that's it. 
Took me almost whole day but it did work.