# Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome) authentication error when logging after lock/suspend

Tags: gnome, 18.04, lock-screen, authentication

I have an issue with screen unlocking. It just rejects my password. And I noticed, it depends on time how long it was locked/suspended! If I unlock 10-20 min. after locking it accepts password and unlocks. But if it has been locked/suspended a hour ago or more it rejects a password. Even if I try to change user, and login again, it rejects. The only way is to reboot. I had this issue on both my machines. On first one (desctop) it has been solved with this solution: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/115963/gnome-authentication-error-when-logging-in-after-lock/ 
But for the second machine (laptop) it doesn't help. Can't google the other working solution. Is it a bug?

Comment: I had the same issue. As a workaround, I can press `Ctrl + Alt + F1` then log in.

Comment: @Edward how do you switch to the desctop after this command-line login?

Comment: I still have this issue.  FYI, I'm using LDAP for authentication.

Comment: Noticed, it happens when keyboard layout switched to russian before locking/suspending. When it was in english, there is no problems with future unlocking. Switching keyboard layout at login screen hasn't effect, even before user switching.

Comment: @RomanVukolov thanks for workaround! I have exactly the same issue still on 18.04.4 latest version with Gnome now past 2 years... It seems a bug with keyboard layout which is not changed in lock screen, but very strange that it hasn't been resolved all this time ( 
Didn't you try Ubuntu 19 Gnome, may be they resolved it only there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: Authentication Error on loging after lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032624/ubuntu-18-04-authentication-error-on-loging-after-lock)