# The pc doesn't launch applications, systemd-journald, Failed to rotate, Failed to write entry

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

After 30 minutes of turn on the pc some extra application installed by me doesn't launch when I need them. The defaults installed applications works fines.

- cant launch applications
- can't install packages. the output say read only file system.

when trying to reboot the pc it get black screen and show something like

```
systemd-journald: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/f29f59... system journal: read only file system
systemd-journald: Failed to write entry (22 items, 738 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Bad message
```

system:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.85.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-31-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-4430 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 15,4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2
```

Root partition have btrfs file system. Bu it have happened with [ext4 file systems too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269870/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-with-ext4-fs-error-and-systemd-journald)

```
chris@k2104:~$ lsblk -f
NAME         FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL      UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                                
├─sda1       ntfs                 New Volume A254DEF854DECDE3                                      
├─sda2       crypto_LUKS 1                   d687b472-083a-401b-9405-fa4e336440ca                  
└─sda3       LVM2_member LVM2 001            2M2yQS-1ckT-Sb7c-m8nm-KKzo-Pbgl-17rYou                
  └─vg2-vms  ext4        1.0                 a85ffc5e-484c-4629-925d-3b65f6546e8d                  
sdb                                                                                                
├─sdb1       btrfs                           9e82231c-74c4-4bb2-907b-1f3e0e7713a7     68,8G    31% /
├─sdb2       LVM2_member LVM2 001            kFAIla-HKFN-TKfb-2dTR-9Y3u-4kCR-ZxiJeD                
│ └─vg1-home ext4        1.0                 d27ee1f7-d35e-4ad8-9722-d36958eb8a1f     78,3G    15% /home
└─sdb3       swap        1                   a191a4aa-78bc-464d-ae44-41ee9bb21a36                  [SWAP]
sdc                                                                                                
├─sdc1       vfat        FAT32               5670-9433                                50,4M    47% /boot/efi
├─sdc2                                                                                             
├─sdc3       ntfs                            00EE92CBEE92B87C                                      
└─sdc4       ntfs                            68E2BA7EE2BA4FD4                                      
sr0                                                                                                
chris@k2104:~$
```

On internet found [this forum](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18742/systemd-journald-cant-write-or-rotate-entries) and have run those commands here

```
dmesg |grep systemd
[ 9286.742113] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 749 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[ 9286.742162] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 738 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[ 9286.742211] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 749 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[ 9286.742261] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 738 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
[ 9286.742312] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 749 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system
```

```
dmesg |grep systemd
[ 1457.129448] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 749 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Bad message
[ 1457.129527] systemd-journald[363]: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal: Journal file corrupted, rotating.
[ 1457.129535] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal: Read-only file system
[ 1457.129550] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000.journal: Read-only file system
[ 1457.129916] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 738 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Bad message
[ 1457.129995] systemd-journald[363]: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal: Journal file corrupted, rotating.
[ 1457.130003] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal: Read-only file system
[ 1457.130009] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to rotate /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000.journal: Read-only file system
[ 1457.130395] systemd-journald[363]: Failed to write entry (22 items, 749 bytes) despite vacuuming, ignoring: Bad message
```

```
sudo journalctl --verify
FAIL: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system@7f05e06386df48d180db2effce0cfec4-00000000000033ec-0005cb6812012c54.journal (Read-only file system)
Failed to create data file: Read-only file system
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal:000000 (of 8388608 bytes, 0%).          
FAIL: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/system.journal (Read-only file system)
Failed to create data file: Read-only file system
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000@e901582910854e349958c8651e322494-0000000000001e80-0005cb5fa4d330fe.journal:000000 (of 8388608 bytes, 0%).
FAIL: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000@e901582910854e349958c8651e322494-0000000000001e80-0005cb5fa4d330fe.journal (Read-only file system)
Failed to create data file: Read-only file system
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000.journal:000000 (of 8388608 bytes, 0%).       
FAIL: /var/log/journal/f29f59c285a64491bbb7ce03db252823/user-1000.journal (Read-only file system)
chris@k2104:~$
```

```
chris@k2104:~$ sudo journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 280.0M in the file system.
chris@k2104:~$
```

I have to reboot the system to fix the problems but after 30 minutes more and less the pc get again the problem.

How can we check SSD problems?
How can we know the problems?
How can we fix that?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: When a filesystem suddenly goes read-only, it's usually because of errors on the media. Check your [disk status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325283/how-do-i-check-the-health-of-a-ssd), and see if it's time to replace your disks.

Answer (score 2):

This script will unmount then remount the var mount point as read-write.

```
sudo umount /var
sudo mount -o remount,rw /var
```

It could be hardware problems so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the problem is about btrfs, the problems was persisting, the problem avoid me to work with the computer normally.
I had reinstalled kubuntu 21.04 in the root partition now with ext4 file format. I tryed to install kde neon but it doesn't recognize the existed /efi/boot partition there and always showed me the message "the system need a efi/boot partition with a fat32 file system, create one"

At today the problem was fixed, but if anyone have had the same problem and know about what would be the origin of the problem feel free to write any insights.

the command `sudo smartctl -t short -a /dev/sda` say that my SSD has a `SSD_Life_left` of `004`, this does worry.

```
chris@k21:~/Documents/web/logindo$ sudo smartctl -t short -a /dev/sda |grep SSD_Life_Left
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   004   004   000    Old_age   Offline      -       96
chris@k21:~/Documents/web/logindo$
```

**Gnome disk (gnome-disk-utility)**
[image]
[image]

Comment: So, the problem went away?

Comment: Yes, at this time the problem haven't appears.